# per blog metadata for plugin

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field

I wish to have my plugin store metadata for each blog in a network (or just one if single site install). Most of the Google results are for post_meta and user_meta but I really need site_meta which does not appear to be the same (only a get method). The data is generally going to be of the form:

```
$metadata['this']['foo'] = 'something';
$metadata['this']['bar'] = 'one thing';
$metadata['that']['foo'] = 'mum';
$metadata['that']['bar'] = 'dad';
```

What is the best way to store this?

Comment: Options are site specific, so you just need to use update_option() and get_option().

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. If you wrote it up as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options are site specific, so you just need to use `update_option()` and `get_option()`.

The network-wide equivalents are `update_network_option()` and `get_network_option()`. Note that `update_site_option()` is just a wrapper for `update_network_option()`, and is an older name from when a multisite network was (confusingly) called a 'site'. The same applies for `get_site_option()`.